# Определение положения в помещении

Tags: android

Обобщенная задача. Определить положение устройства (телефон, плашнет) в помещении.
Теоретически в любой момент времени устройство может видеть несколько точек доступа.
С помощью `WifiManager.getScanResults()` получаем уровни сигнала до всех видимых точек доступа. Каким образом уровень сигнала преобразовать в расстояния для дальнейшей триангуляции?

Если поможет, можно заранее просчитать координаты на некой координатной сетке всех точек доступа (ну по крайней мере тех, к которым есть физический доступ).

Задача также осложняется наличием стен и перекрытий (несколько этажей).

ЗЫ ищу любые варианты сабжа, wifi был бы идеальным вариантом, если бы получилось.

Comment: А какова требуется точность?

Comment: идеально до метра. ну чтоб найти девайс. а вообще просто интересно получится ли вообще какую-то точность получить.

Comment: Думаю тут надо проводить исследования. На характер влияния стен на проходимость радио сигнала. Плюс, разная частота вайфая может иметь разные параметры распространения. Плюс, мощность излучения конкретного роутера надо знать. Например более мощный сигнал не обязательно самый ближайший (даже если исключить стены)

Comment: @Чад, да, видимо придется оцифровывать все помещение, ходить и делать замеры на каждом кв. метре. различиями в оборудовании можно бы пренебречь - подконтрольные AP могли бы быть одинаковыми, например... ну и видимо точность тоже можно будет узнать только эмпирически...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Тут есть не плохое описание, даже исходники под андрод есть](http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/spring11/group02/documents/default.html).     
[+видео, как работает](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OV-9OPnu3cM&noredirect=1)

Полтора года хотел взять эту тему в качестве диплома, но побоялся, что не хватит времени на реализацию хорошего прототипа.

Доп. инфа.
http://trillworks.com/nick/2011/11/25/real-time-indoor-navigation-for-android-phones/
http://hkr.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:475619/FULLTEXT02.pdf

Comment: Шикарно! Спасибо, буду разбираться.